# How can I find unused dependencies in a Maven reactor build?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I'm struggling with `mvn dependency:analyze`. I couldn't get the plugin to work with a reactor build. Instead of recursively building a list of used dependencies, I see unused dependencies per module which is pretty useless. Let's say I have two modules `A` and `B` where `B` depends on `A`. `A` depend on `commons-email`.

The dependency plugin tells me that `commons-email` is an "unused declared dependency" of `B` which I don't understand: The dependency isn't mentioned in the POM of `B` and it's used in `A`, so the message is wrong, no matter how I look at it. Also, I don't get this message for `A`, so the plugin knows that `A` is using the dependency.

On top of that, I get a ton of "used undeclared dependencies" - one warning for each transitive dependency.

Is there a way to configure the dependency plugin to provide some useful information? If not, is there a replacement which can compute a "convex hull" of all the reachable imports?

Answer (score 3):

Regarding the unused declared dependency , you might be inheriting it from a parent pom.

Regarding the used undeclared dependencies for the transitive dependencies : if you directly reference any class from a transitive dependency in a module - e.g. in an import - then the module should declare a direct dependency, even if there is already a transitive dependency .
 provide versions for all your
Use dependency management in your parent pom for all your  dependencies instead of declaring the versions over and over again in  all of your modules.

Comment: I'm using depenendency management elements in the parent POM already. But I really see no point to duplicate all the transitive dependencies in all my 500 POMs. I have "interface modules" which make external code (= dependencies) easier to digest for my projects. Repeating the transitive dependencies in my POMs which use the interface modules seems like a huge waste of time (and a violation of DRY). Do you have any evidence or links supporting your position?

Comment: Consider you upgrade dependency X from v1 to v2. In v1, X depended transitively on A, but in v2, it does not do it anymore. Your code, however, uses A directly. It would still compile if you had a dependency on A, even after the upgrade of X - but since you don't have a depenency on A, it breaks. As I see it, the public API of a module are *only* the public classes of that module (unless in some "internal" package), not the transitive dependencies of the module. It may be a matter of taste/convention. OSGi allows making this more explicit, but normal JARs do not, so I tend to be conservative.

Comment: Okay, now it starts to make more sense. I haven't had this case (more often, a dependency brings more to the table than I wanted (like many `commons` packages which have been moved to `org.apache.commons`) and I suddenly find two copies on my classpath. I don't remember ever missing a dependency after a version upgrade but chances are that I could fix the problem so easily that it didn't stuck in my memory.